# Validar formulário e Enviar email

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Eu tenho um código onde faço a validação dos campos em brancos, porém eu queria saber como faço para que quando os campos estejam preenchidos ele execute o `submit` para a página **send.php**

Form:

```
 <form method="post" action="send.php">
<div class="form-group">                    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label>Nome</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" name="nome" placeholder="Insira seu Nome">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group" hidden>   
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label>E-mail</label>
            <input type="fqemail" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Insira seu E-mail">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label>Celular</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="celular" name="telefone">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group" hidden>   
    <div class="row">
        <select id="pais" hidden></select>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label>Estado</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="estado" name="estado">
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label>Cidade</label>
            <select type="text" class="form-control" id="cidade" name="cidade" placeholder="Insira sua Cidade">
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group" hidden>   
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label>Mensagem</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="mensagem" name="mensagem" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>                 
</div>                  
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary valida" id="send">Enviar</button>
```

Validação:

```
$(".valida").click(function(){    

    // remove as mensagens de erro
    $(".erromsg").remove();

    // verificar se os campos foram preenchidos
    var nome = $("#nome");
    var email = $("#email");
    var celular = $("#celular");
    var estado = $("#estado");
    var cidade = $("#cidade");

    // Mensagem de erro padrão a ser inserida após o campo
    var erromsg = '<div class="erromsg">Por favor, preencha o campo <span></span></div>';

    if(!nome.val() || nome.val().length < 5){
       nome.after(erromsg);
       $(".erromsg span").text("Nome*");
       return;
    }

    if(!email.val()){
       email.after(erromsg);
       $(".erromsg span").text("E-mail*");
       return;
    }


    if(!celular.val()){
       celular.after(erromsg);
       $(".erromsg span").text("Celular*");
       return;
    }

    if(!estado.val()){
       estado.after(erromsg);
       $(".erromsg span").text("Capital*");
       return;
    }

    if(!cidade.val()){
       cidade.after(erromsg);
       $(".erromsg span").text("Estado*");
       return;
    }
});
```

Comment: eu não entendi bem você quer que ele só envie caso todos os campos forem preenchidos ? e porque os outros campos estão hidden ?

Comment: eu to ocultando com hidden, para mostrar o próximo campo após o primeiro ser preenchido, então como eu to usando o type="button" quando termino de preencher o formulário, não executa o submit e eu não sei fazer essa parte funcionar rs

Comment: vocÊ pode usar um button e usar o type="submit" não resolveria seu caso ?

Comment: quando eu uso o type="submit", ele não valida os campos, ele executa direto o send.php, como eu to usando o botão de Enviar para validar toda vez que é clicado nele, por isso esotu com esse problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloque no final da função do evento `click` um trigger de `submit`:

```
$(this).closest("form").submit();
```

Como você está usando `return` em todas as validações, essa linha acima só será executada se passar por todos os `if`'s.

O `$(this)` é o elemento que disparou o evento (no caso o botão). O `.closest("form")` irá buscar a tag `form` onde está o botão e o `.submit()` envia o formulário.

Ficará assim:

```
$(".valida").click(function(){

   // códigos das validações

   $(this).closest("form").submit(); // última linha da função

});
```

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Montei uma base pra ajudar a resolver o seu problema, você pode usar o [`submit();`](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) e usar uma lógica básica de verificação de **retorno false**, quando ocorrer um `return false;` ele não irá submeter o formulário, caso não nenhum `return false` ele submete o formulário.

```js
//  Bind the event handler to the "submit" JavaScript event
$('form').submit(function () {

    // Get the Login Name value and trim it
    var name = $.trim($('#nome').val());

    // Check if empty of not
    if (name === '') {
        alert('O Campo Nome está vazio.');
        return false;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <form method="post" action="send.php">
      <div class="form-group">                    
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                  <label>Nome</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" name="nome" placeholder="Insira seu Nome">
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
                    
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary valida" id="send">Enviar</button>
  </form>
```

A validação realizada, remove os espaços entre a primeira e ultima letra, e verifica se existe algum texto, e caso sim retorna um alert. no seu caso você coloque a atualização do campo demarcado.

Testa ai e vÊ se funciona para seu caso.

Answer (score 0):

Pode dar um id ao seu formulário 
e depois fazer submit por jQuery

$('#id').submit();